# What is the right way to insert an equation within a pseudo code

Tags: latex, equation

I start writing my note in Latex and I am trying to write a pseudo code based on this equation:

[image: equation]

Here is my code I have tried so far.

```latex
\begin{addmargin}[10mm]{0mm}
     \textbf{Repeat until convergence:} \ \{ 
     \[
         \theta_j := \theta_j + \alpha \sum_{i=1}^m(y^{(i)}-h_\theta(x^{(i)})) \ x_j^{(i)} \quad (\text{for every} \ j).
     \]
     \}
  \end{addmargin}
```

I still think it is a bit messy. Do you have an easier way to write this?

Comment: is it giving any problems? if not and you want to review your code submit it at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: Yes, it still has a problem that the equation is indented as a result of displayed equation command \[ ... \]. As you can see in the attached figure, it looks like the equation indented by one tab which is the same way as we write our code.

Comment: @dfri Thanks you for reminding me of marking your answer. I like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question should probably be moved to tex.stackexchange.

---

There exists several different neat Latex packages specifically with the purpose of writing pseudocode. One of the more simple ways to do it is by using the [`Algorithmicx`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms#Typesetting_using_the_algorithmicx_package) package (package documentation [here](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf)), specifically the `algpseudocode` part of it.

Here is an MWE for your pseudocode using Algoritmicx:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for each}}

\begin{document}
\noindent Let $\mathcal{J} := \{1, ..., n\}$.

\begin{algorithmic}
    \While {Some convergence criteria is not fulfilled ...}
        \ForAll {$j \in \mathcal{J}$}
            \State $\theta_j \gets \theta_j + \alpha \sum_{i=1}^m(y^{(i)}-h_\theta(x^{(i)})) \ x_j^{(i)}$
        \EndFor   
        \State {... update some convergence measure} \Comment{Describe convergence measure}
    \EndWhile 
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Note that, at the fourth non-empty line, I've overloaded the text of `\ForAll` command from algorithmicx (`\algorithmicforall`), to become "**for ... each**" rather than "**for ... all**".

Note also that, generally, only comments may contain text in pseudocode, so the sentences "*Some convergence criteria is not fulfilled ...*" and "*... update some convergence measure*" above should be replaced with however your define convergence of algorithm/equation.

Comment: Thanks you. Your answer looks a bit more formal than I expected, but I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want, from the packages `algorithm` and `algorithmic`

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Gradient Descent}\label{alg-gd}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE Initialize \( \theta_{0} = k\in \R^d \)
\STATE Initialize \( t \leftarrow 0 \)
\REPEAT
\STATE \( \forall j \in \{1,..., d\}, \theta_{j,t+1} \leftarrow \theta_{j,t} - \alpha \frac{\p }{\p \theta_{j} } L(\theta )\bigg|_{\theta = \theta_{t} }  \)
\STATE \( t \leftarrow t + 1 \)
\UNTIL{convergence}
```

which gives,

[image]

Note: if you are using it in beamer, put `\begin{algorithm}[H]` in the line above instead of just `\begin{algorithm}`